# WiFi adaptor no longer found for Dell XPS 15 9500 (QCA6390 PCI device)

Tags: drivers, wireless, dell, atheros

My WiFi adaptor has disappeared!

I have had this working via updating to a newer kernel version than was provided with 20.04 (am currently on 5.11.12) which I believe should support the bundled card - and it had been working without issue. However a couple of days ago it seems to have gotten lost after some updates, and now isn't even shown in the bios. Have tried a firmware reinstall and bios update to no avail.

I'm expecting to see this:

```
sudo lspci -nn | grep Qualcomm
6c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Device [17cb:1101] (rev 01)
```

as described in https://medium.com/@tomas.heiskanen/dell-xps-15-9500-wifi-on-ubuntu-20-04-d5f1c218e78a but the device isn't showing up any more.

Answer (score 2):

Install the `linux-oem-20.04` package, it will install the following dependencies `linux-headers-oem-20.04`, `linux-image-oem-20.04` and `linux-modules-*-oem` including the `ath11k` kernel module:

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04
sudo reboot
```

[Installing ath11k](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath11k/installation)